# Capture db2 sql results in shell script

Tags: sql, shell, db2

I have a shell script which will connect to database and get the results. My script is like

```
#!/bin/bash
getResults()
{
    db2 "connect to ${1} user ${2} using ${3}"
    db2 "set schema ${4}"
    status=`db2 -x "select status from results where id=1"`
    echo $status
}
#MAIN STARS HERE
getResults dbname foo bar test
```

Now I wanted to get multiple columns from results tables using

```
select status,timestamp from results where id=1
```

How can I run the above query and capture both status and timestamp into two different shell variables using single query instead of running 2 differnt queries like

```
#!/bin/bash
getResults()
{
    db2 "connect to ${1} user ${2} using ${3}"
    db2 "set schema ${4}"
    status=`db2 -x "select status from results where id=1"`
    echo $status
     timestamp=`db2 -x "select timestamp from results where id=1"`
    echo $timestamp

}
#MAIN STARS HERE
getResults dbname foo bar test
```

My results table is like:

```
create table (id number, status char(1), timestamp datetime);
```

And data is like

```
1 P <some ts>
2 F <some ts>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is the table?  If it's in the database, you should be able to run it as a regular insert/create statement...  Can't help with the shell script, sorry.

Comment: my table is in database and I wanted to retrive data from that table using above query from my shell script. I know how run sql's from db2 cnsole.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the database connection you make in the getResults function is not visible to the subshell (i.e. when you call `db2 -x`).  Using backticks invokes a new shell.

To make this work you need to keep your query in the same shell:

```
db2 "connect to ${1} user ${2} using ${3}"
db2 "set schema ${4}"

db2 -x "select status,timestamp from results where id = 1" | while read status timestamp ; do
    echo $status
    echo $timestamp
done
```

Note that with the while loop here you will output multiple lines if your query returns more than 1 row.  It's easy to modify the SQL to return only 1 row.

Comment: Looks like its gonna solve my problem. Let me test this tomorrow and get back to you. Thanks for your answer.